# How to set div height same for all mobiles in android by using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.height').css('height', $(window).height());
```

I am using this for same height of div on windows but in android mobile it is not working fine any answers

Comment: why use js for this? why not just use css?

Comment: I am using one plug-in sliderjs in that i want to fix the same height for all mobiles so i used  $(window).height()); it is working in browser but in android it is not working rather than window any other is there for android

Comment: Why you're not using resize event because it occur issue when you change your view

Comment: Can u send me the link for that if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.height').css('height', $(window).innerHeight());
```